# What strategies exist for compounding and overriding in a claims-based authorization system?

Tags: authorization, claims-based-identity

We've built a basic claims-based authorization system into a REST API, where a custom claims provider runs on incoming requests and application-specific roles are mapped to "permission" claims.

For example, imagine an app with Accounts, users, and roles. For Basic Accounts, the Owner role is mapped to the "View-Account" claim and the "Modify-Account" claim, while the Assistant role only maps to "View-Account." However, for Premium Accounts, both Owner and Assistant map to both claims.

User Bob has the Owner role on BasicAccount 123, but *no* role on PremiumAccount 456. User Ann has the Assistant role on BasicAccount 123 *and* PreiumAccount 456. Given those users and their roles, Bob will have the claims "View-Account-123" and "Modify-Account-123", while Ann will have the claims "View-Account-123", "View-Account-456", and "Modify-Account-456".

This is working well for all the simple scenarios we've had to implement so far; API controllers are annotated with a custom attribute (this is C#/.Net) that specifies which claim is required to access each endpoint/method.

So now we need to implement locking of an Account, such that nobody can modify it, regardless of their role. The question is, what are our options for implementing that kind of override logic using claims? It seems like, as a first step, we need new claims to represent the permission to lock and unlock an Account, and to map them from the appropriate role(s). But I don't want to embed the "compound" or override logic into the places that use the claims - all those API endpoint methods should not have to know about the locked state. Nor do I want to force (or rely on) every new claim that we add to be aware of the lock "override" claim/logic.

This is my first foray into implementing application-specific claims-bsaed authorization, so any thoughts or experience on strategies are appreciated.

Note that I'm not interested in re-designing the entire authorization infrastructure to be based on XACML or something else (as suggested in the duplicate question vote). We are going with claims-based authorization internally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RESTful API authorization on entities/resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641024/restful-api-authorization-on-entities-resources)

Comment: No, that's a somewhat different question and not in scope for what I want to do.

Comment: Claims-based has its limitations that ABAC addresses

Comment: @DavidBrossard maybe so, but this question is specifically about claims-based. ABAC also has it's own tradeoffs that may or may not be justifiable in a specific situation. In any case, it's out of scope for my question.

Comment: Fair enough. In all fairness, the key challenge with claims-based is that it is framework-specific and still tightly couples authZ with business logic.

Comment: @DavidBrossard can you remove the duplicate vote? I fear that seeing it at the top of the question discourages others from reading and/or answering.

Comment: Sure thing, done